# Все ваши слова (—) не более чем обман

Tags: тире

Подскажите, пожалуйста, обязательно ли ставить тире: Все ваши слова (—) не более чем обман.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Все ваши словА — не более чем обман.***

Тире в этом предложении  **интонационное**, обозначает паузу в речи.

При наличии между подлежащим и сказуемым частиц, наречий, вводных слов **тире не является обязательным**, например:

***Все ваши слова не более чем обмАн, теперь это ясно***.

При другой расстановке логических ударений пауза не делается и тире не ставится.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Тире не ставится:

4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, иногда — наречие, союз, частица: Дубава, кажется, друг Корчагина (Н. О); Риск, как известно, дело благородное; Необдуманный поступок вообще шаг опасный; Сергеев теперь известный художник; Пихта тоже дерево смолистое; Март только начало весны.

Таким образом, тире не ставится по основному правилу, но ставится для интонационного деления предложения на две части.

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно. Тогда и паузы не будет.

Но с тире вторая часть должна произноситься с чуть более сильной интонацией.

Answer (score 0):

Тире как минимум желательно.

Здесь пропущен глагол-связка ("есть") между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженным существительным в им. п. В этой ситуации при некоторых огоорках тире обязательно.

Однако, сложность тут в определении, нужно ли рассматривать конструкцию "не более чем" как самостоятельный член предложения (здесь по функции это усилительная частица). Если да, то тире - факультативно.
Но я все же не рассматривал бы эту часть как нарушающую условия правила. Тогда тире обязательно.

Чисто практически в любом случае тут проще поставить тире, чем думать о его  обязательности.